# How to make a new WCF service when I only have a WCF client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I have an application that call an asmx web service, but the service no longer exist. There is no code, no wsdl, nothing.

The client is a simple console app which has a service reference to the service that no longer exist. The client must not be modified in any way except changing the URL and binding data in its app.confing. No re-compilation allowed.

If I can create a new service, I can implement the calls needed. How can I make a service that works with the old client?

Comment: @RyanWilson the question is how to I create a service so that it is compatible with the client. Not just how create any service.

Comment: Take a look at what the client is doing, look at what kind of request it creates (you can use tools to examine the raw contents of the request if need be), and then it will be easier to write a server which can receive a request in that format. If you're still struggling after that, show us the relevant code from your client, plus any info you've gathered about the request content, and maybe we can help you with it. Right now we can't give you a definite answer, all we can do is tell you, as I've done, to go and get more information.

Comment: The WCF client will call the server's method. The client only knows the service interface, and the implementation of the interface is on the WCF server. If there is no server-side code, you will not know how the interface is implemented. I think your needs cannot be realized.

Comment: That's a good point. Unless you're very familiar already with what the service does behind the scenes then it might be hard to recreate anything more than a superficial replacement. You might be able to get it to accept the request being sent by your application, but do you know exactly what it does with the data after that?

Comment: @DingPeng So, I am not interested in the implementation of the service methods, I know how to implement the methods. I am interested in making a service that has the same service contract because the clients cannot be recompiled and redistributed.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The new server only needs to have the same endpoints, bindings, and contract as the old server, so the client can run without updating the service reference.

If the client's endpoint information looks like this:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"
            contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
```

The new server should look something like this:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.